# Settings bundle implementation for jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, settings.bundle

I'm taking an app which I've developed using Xcode and I'm planning on sending it to a Cydia repository for use on jailbroken devices. Given as I've only developed for the iTunes store, the process for building, signing, using ldid, etc is quite new for me.

I've gotten my app (a simple open source Bitcoin ticker) to install on my jailbroken iOS7 device by copying to the device using ssh, and then 'ldid'-ing it, followed by a respring. I'm having quite a time getting the settings bundle to work properly. I've taken a look at using PreferenceLoader and I've copied the Settings.bundle to the `/Library/PrefrenceBundles` folder with the name `"MyApp.bundle"`, and a `"MyApp.plist"` to `/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences`. The bundle displays in the settings menu, but says "There was an error loading the preference bundle for MyApp".

I've taken a look at some open source jailbreak apps and have tried to mimic, as closely as possible, the setup of the settings bundle and the plist. I still can't get it to work. Please forgive my lack of jailbreak dev knowledge, everyone has to start somewhere...:)

Comment: I mean, it's a programming question....

Comment: Have you looked [at this documentation](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader)?  If so, are you trying the *simple*, or *bundle* approach?  Do you need **code** to execute in your Settings pages, or are they just basic switches, sliders, and text fields? Are you simply trying to use the same Settings.bundle you would for an App Store app?

Comment: I've taken a look at that guide, yeah. All I want to do is use the same (or a modified) version of the Settings.bundle that I would use for the App Store app. It's just basic switches and multivalues, no executable code. My guess is that I need to use the bundle approach, I think.

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, you need to create a new settings definition for your jailbreak apps.  You can certainly create all the same settings and defaults, and controls, but not with the same Settings.bundle files.  I would follow the "Simple" example in the link I provided.  That's always worked for me.